# Integral of normal random variable: $ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}-2t\right)}~dx$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

How can we show the following?
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}-2t\right)}~dx=(1-2\sigma^2t)^\frac{-1}{2}$$

Comment: For every $a\ne0$, $$\int_\mathbb Re^{-x^2/(2a^2)}dx=\sqrt{2\pi a^2}$$ as anybody who has seen even once in their life a normal density should know. Use this with $$\frac1{a^2}=\frac1{\sigma^2}-2t$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the [Gaussian Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), defined by:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}~dx=\sqrt{\pi} \tag{1}$$

---

One way to start is to write your integral as:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sigma^2}-2t\right)}dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}(1-2t\sigma^2)}~dx$$

We must figure out a substitution to get the integral above, into a form such that we can apply $(1)$. Hence, it becomes obvious to use the substitution:
$$u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}\cdot \sigma}\cdot \sqrt{1-2t\sigma^2} \iff x=\frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot \sigma}{\sqrt{1-2t\sigma^2}}\cdot u \iff dx=\frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot \sigma}{\sqrt{1-2t\sigma^2}}~du$$
Hence giving:
$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}(1-2t\sigma^2)}~dx&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2}\cdot \frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot \sigma}{\sqrt{1-2t\sigma^2}}~du\\&=\frac{\sqrt{2}\cdot \sigma}{\sqrt{1-2t\sigma^2}}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2}~du  \end{align}$$
We now have an integral in the form of $(1)$! Applying the Gaussian Integral, and simplifying will give you the result you require.